# Using @detail_route keeps returning either a 404, no ID or keyword argument

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

Here's my @detail_route

```
@detail_route()
def children(self, request):
    parent = self.get_object()
    children = parent.parent_children.all()
    serializer = ChildSerializer(children)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

If I DON'T include a PK or some **kwargs I get the error:

```
children() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
```

If I DO add PK or **kwargs to the children parameters I get the error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'
```

If I add PK to the parameters AND I pass PK to the get_object() I get 404 errors for the set, even though it is in there.

I'm lost as to why these are all producing such different errors. My expectation is that if I go to `/api/parent/7/children` I'd get the list of children for that parent

Comment: But you need the PK for of the parent in order to GET the children, hence the detail_route. If you use list_route, you have no PK to get the children with

Comment: If I use a list_route I don't have access to the PK of the Parent which is what I need to get the children of the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Django REST Framework 2.4, you should pass `many=True` when initializing serializers for lists of data, such as querysets.

In order to fix the issue you are hitting, you should let `pk` and `format` be passed into the route and set `many=True` on `ChildSerializer`.

```
@detail_route()
def children(self, request, pk, format=None):
    parent = self.get_object()
    children = parent.parent_children.all()
    serializer = ChildSerializer(children, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

This will tell the serializer to interpret the incoming data as a list, instead of a single object.